# Prevent Index Small from returning duplicate values

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to return a unique list of values that match certain criteria.  I have been able to generate the a list that I am wanting but it also returns duplicates; how do I remove them from the list?  I have looked up either using UNIQUE function but that didn't seem to work correctly.

Here is the code I have in C7 that runs to C100:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B,SMALL(IF((Sunday!$D$1='Trailers Closed (OD)'!M:M) * (Sunday!$D$2='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Y:Y) * (Sunday!$D$3='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Z:Z),ROW('Trailers Closed (OD)'!A:A)),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

[image: Unique List]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER('Trailers Closed (OD)'!B:B,(Sunday!D1='Trailers Closed (OD)'!M:M)*(Sunday!D2='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Y:Y)*(Sunday!D3='Trailers Closed (OD)'!Z:Z),""))
```

[image]